# How to use resultJsonFactory in Model file magento2

Tags: magento2, model, json

I have used below code to print response from my Model file.

```
<?php

class CountrylistManagement implements 
   \Vendor\Module\Api\CountrylistManagementInterface
{
protected $_storeManager;
protected $objectManager;
protected $_resource;
protected $resultJsonFactory;
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
    \Magento\Framework\ObjectManagerInterface $objectManager,       
    \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
    \Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection $resource,
    \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\JsonFactory $resultJsonFactory
) {
    $this->_objectManager = $objectManager;     
    $this->_storeManager = $storeManager;
    $this->_resource = $resource;
    $this->resultJsonFactory = $resultJsonFactory;      
    parent::__construct($context);
}
     public function postCountrylist($params)
{
    $resultArr = array();
    $request =  json_encode($params);
    $resultArr['message'] = "Success";
    $resultArr['code'] = 200;
    $resultJson = $this->resultJsonFactory->create();
    $resultJson->setData($resultArr);
    return $resultJson;
  }
}
```

Here I am trying to print the json response from the model file,
The above code works well from controller.

Can we use **$resultJson = $this->resultJsonFactory->create();** to print the response from model file?

right now its not working for me. if anyone can look into this and update where i am doing wrong please.

Answer (score 1):

Please donot use `\Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\JsonFactory`

Use 
`Magento\Framework\Serialize\Serializer\Json` for  make json response.

You  have to  make use  `serialize($resultArr)` for getting json response.

### Code:

```
<?php

namespace Devamitbera\Systemconfig\Model;

class CountrylistManagement implements \Vendor\Module\Api\CountrylistManagementInterface {

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Serialize\Serializer\Json
     */
    private $json;
    protected $_storeManager;
    protected $objectManager;
    protected $_resource;

    public function __construct(
            \Magento\Framework\ObjectManagerInterface $objectManager,
            \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
            \Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection $resource,
            \Magento\Framework\Serialize\Serializer\Json $json
    ) {
        $this->_objectManager = $objectManager;
        $this->_storeManager = $storeManager;
        $this->_resource = $resource;
        $this->json = $json;
    }

    public function postCountrylist($params) {
        $resultArr = array();
        $resultArr['message'] = "Success";
        $resultArr['code'] = 200;

        return $this->json->serialize($resultArr);
    }

}
```

Comment: can u update to my question please,

Comment: I've used like below now, use Magento\Framework\Serialize\Serializer\Json;
then return serialize($resultArr);, but still its not working

Comment: I think you need  to remove `\Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,` and `parent::__construct($context);`

Comment: now i am able to print in json format, "{\"status code\":\"200\",,\"result\":\"Success\"}" can we print as like this, {
  "status code": 200,
  "result": "Success"
  }

Comment: previously i used like this, echo json_encode($resultArr,JSON_PRETTY_PRINT); this was working fine, but i need to use in magento format

Comment: OPPS you need to remove `$request = json_encode($params);`

Comment: Two times json_encode happened !! :(

Comment: hi @Amit. I am not using $request variable anywhere, only bothered about $resultArr, this array i want to print in json format, $request was used for different purpose, that is nowhere related here

Comment: then use `return json_encode($resultArr,JSON_PRETTY_PRINT)`  instead of  `return $this->json->serialize($resultArr);`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/94006/discussion-between-jafar-pinjar-and-amit-bera).

Comment: hello @Amit, pls check chat

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue and I just answered another similar question, I found that JsonFactory doesnt work for me in webapi or Model class, so there is another solution to return a json with the `Magento\Framework\Webapi\Rest\Response` class.

**Try this:**

```
$resultArr = array();
$resultArr['message'] = "Success";
$resultArr['code'] = 200;

return $this->response->setBody(json_encode($resultArr))->sendResponse();
```